# constructor parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

I am trying to learn about constructors in JavaScript. I was watching some tutorial where this constructor:

```js
    class Human{
        constructor() {
          this.gender = 'male'
         
        }
        printGender(){
          console.log(this.gender);
        }
      }
```

was also written with shorter syntax that looked like this:

```js
    class Human{
        gender = 'male';
      
        printGender = () =>{
          console.log(this.gender);
        }
      }
```

I have no problem understanding this. However, what if I have some parameters. Like this for example:

```js
    class Human{
        constructor(gender, height) {
          this.gender = gender;
          this.height = height;
    
        }
        printGender(){
          console.log(this.gender);
        }
      }
```

How do I write this shorter syntax and also have parameters? I could not find anything about this question. Any help?

Comment: Please avoid the term "ES7" in this context. ES7 came out in 2016 and does not include these features. These are just experimental proposals.

Comment: No problem, replace it with experimental proposals

Comment: If whatever you were reading referred to this syntax as "ES7", you should probably stop reading it and find a different source. This is part of a [TC39 proposal currently in progress](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#field-declarations).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guidance. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you wrote would be acceptable.

You could additionally do:

```
class Human {
    gender;
    height;

    constructor(gender, height) {
      this.gender = gender;
      this.height = height;

    }
    printGender(){
      console.log(this.gender);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question is how can I do it without the constructor like second example, but with parameters.

Comment: You can't... That's the only way to your constructor's arguments. Unless, you have a super class that sets an argument to a property - i.e. within a `React.Component` you can use `this.props` within your subclass to set a property, because the super `Component` class assigned the props argument to the `props` property.

Answer (score -1):

Upfront field declarations is just a self documentation. To set the instance value we've to use constructor method during instantiation of the class like @Tobiq said.